# Obj-c - Get color on tap from camera view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want my user to be able to tap an area on their screen, and have the color that they tapped returned. I'm successfully able to do this with my below code. That being said, it returns the background color of self.previewView (which is white), and NOT the color of what is tapped inside its subview (which is the camera).

How can I have my below code return the color tapped in self.videoPreviewLayer (subview of self.previewView)?

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface CaptureViewController : UIViewController <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureSession *captureSession;
@property (nonatomic) AVCapturePhotoOutput *stillImageOutput;
@property (nonatomic) AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *videoPreviewLayer;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *colorPicked;

@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *previewView;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
   

    self.captureSession = [AVCaptureSession new];
    self.captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto;
    
    AVCaptureDevice *backCamera = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if (!backCamera) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to access back camera!");
        return;
    }
    
    
    NSError *error;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:backCamera
                                                                        error:&error];
    if (!error) {
     
        
        self.stillImageOutput = [AVCapturePhotoOutput new];

        if ([self.captureSession canAddInput:input] && [self.captureSession canAddOutput:self.stillImageOutput]) {
            
            [self.captureSession addInput:input];
            [self.captureSession addOutput:self.stillImageOutput];
            [self setupLivePreview];
        }
        
        dispatch_queue_t globalQueue =  dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0);
        dispatch_async(globalQueue, ^{
            [self.captureSession startRunning];
           
        });
        
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            self.videoPreviewLayer.frame = self.previewView.bounds;
            
          
            
        });
        
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error Unable to initialize back camera: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }
    
    

    
}


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
     [self.previewView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
     self.previewView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    
}

- (void)setupLivePreview {
    
    self.videoPreviewLayer = [AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer layerWithSession:self.captureSession];
    if (self.videoPreviewLayer) {
        
        self.videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect;
        self.videoPreviewLayer.connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait;
        [self.previewView.layer addSublayer:self.videoPreviewLayer];
        
  
    }
}

-(void)tapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer  {
    
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
    CGPoint p = { round(location.x), round(location.y) };
    self.colorPicked.backgroundColor = [self colorInViewAtPoint:p];
    
    
    UIColor *mylovelycolor = [self colorInViewAtPoint:p];
     
 
       NSLog(@"MY LOVELY COLOR %@", mylovelycolor.CGColor);
       
       const CGFloat *components = CGColorGetComponents(mylovelycolor.CGColor);
       NSLog(@"Red: %f", components[0]);
       NSLog(@"Green: %f", components[1]);
       NSLog(@"Blue: %f", components[2]);
       NSLog(@"Alpha: %f", CGColorGetAlpha(mylovelycolor.CGColor));
       

           int red = components[0] * 255;
           int green = components[1] * 255;
           int blue = components[2] * 255;
       
    
}


-(UIColor *)colorInViewAtPoint:(CGPoint)p {
    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    // correct panlocation vs bitmapt coordintes
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -p.x, -p.y);
    [self.previewView.layer renderInContext:context];
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
   
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0
                           green:pixel[1]/255.0
                            blue:pixel[2]/255.0
                           alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];
    

}
```

Comment: You could implement extracting the frames from the camera into UIImages/CGImages and then get a specific pixel color from current image/frame. Here is a nice tutorial on how to extract frames from the camera into UIImages: https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-camera-frames-extraction-d2c0f80ed05a

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following code:

Convert point：

```
- (CGPoint)convertPoint:(CGPoint)viewPoint fromView:(UIView *)view {

CGPoint imagePoint = viewPoint;

CGSize imageSize = self.size;
CGSize viewSize  = view.bounds.size;

CGFloat ratioX = viewSize.width / imageSize.width;
CGFloat ratioY = viewSize.height / imageSize.height;

UIViewContentMode contentMode = view.contentMode;

switch (contentMode) {
case UIViewContentModeScaleToFill:
case UIViewContentModeRedraw:
{
    imagePoint.x /= ratioX;
    imagePoint.y /= ratioY;
    break;
}

case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit:
case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill:
{
    CGFloat scale;

    if (contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit) {
        scale = MIN(ratioX, ratioY);
    }
    else /*if (contentMode == UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill)*/ {
        scale = MAX(ratioX, ratioY);
    }

    // Remove the x or y margin added in FitMode
    imagePoint.x -= (viewSize.width  - imageSize.width  * scale) / 2.0f;
    imagePoint.y -= (viewSize.height - imageSize.height * scale) / 2.0f;

    imagePoint.x /= scale;
    imagePoint.y /= scale;

    break;
}

case UIViewContentModeCenter:
{
    imagePoint.x -= (viewSize.width - imageSize.width)  / 2.0f;
    imagePoint.y -= (viewSize.height - imageSize.height) / 2.0f;

    break;
}

case UIViewContentModeTop:
{
    imagePoint.x -= (viewSize.width - imageSize.width)  / 2.0f;

    break;
}

case UIViewContentModeBottom:
{
    imagePoint.x -= (viewSize.width - imageSize.width)  / 2.0f;
    imagePoint.y -= (viewSize.height - imageSize.height);

    break;
}

case UIViewContentModeLeft:
{
    imagePoint.y -= (viewSize.height - imageSize.height) / 2.0f;

    break;
}

case UIViewContentModeRight:
{
    imagePoint.x -= (viewSize.width - imageSize.width);
    imagePoint.y -= (viewSize.height - imageSize.height) / 2.0f;

    break;
}

case UIViewContentModeTopRight:
{
    imagePoint.x -= (viewSize.width - imageSize.width);

    break;
}


case UIViewContentModeBottomLeft:
{
    imagePoint.y -= (viewSize.height - imageSize.height);

    break;
}


case UIViewContentModeBottomRight:
{
    imagePoint.x -= (viewSize.width - imageSize.width);
    imagePoint.y -= (viewSize.height - imageSize.height);

    break;
}

case UIViewContentModeTopLeft:
default:
{
    break;
}
}
return imagePoint;
}

+ (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer
{
    //NSLog(@"imageFromSampleBuffer: called");

    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);

    CGFloat degrees = 90.f;
    CGFloat radians = degrees * (M_PI / 180.f);
    CGContextRotateCTM(context, radians);

    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    //UIDeviceOrientation *deviceOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    //    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage scale:1 orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}
```

Pick color with point：

```
- (UIColor*)pickColorWithPoint:(CGPoint)atPoint pixelFormatType: (UInt32)format {

UIColor* color = nil;

CGImageRef cgImage =  self.CGImage;
size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(cgImage);
size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(cgImage);
NSUInteger x = (NSUInteger)floor(atPoint.x) * self.scale;
NSUInteger y = (NSUInteger)floor(atPoint.y) * self.scale;

if ((x < width) && (y < height)) {
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGImageGetDataProvider(cgImage);
    CFDataRef bitmapData = CGDataProviderCopyData(provider);

    const UInt8 *data = CFDataGetBytePtr(bitmapData);

    size_t offset = ((width * y) + x) * 4;

    if (format == kCVPixelFormatType_32RGBA) {

        UInt8 red   = data[offset];
        UInt8 green = data[offset + 1];
        UInt8 blue  = data[offset + 2];
        UInt8 alpha = data[offset + 3];
        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:alpha/255.0f];

    } else if (format == kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA) {

        UInt8 blue   = data[offset + 0];
        UInt8 green = data[offset + 1];
        UInt8 red  = data[offset + 2];

        color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
    }

    CFRelease(bitmapData);
}

return color;

//    CFDataRef pixelData = CGDataProviderCopyData(CGImageGetDataProvider(self.CGImage));
//    const UInt8* data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData);
//    
//    int pixelInfo = ((self.size.width  * atPoint.y) + atPoint.x) * 4;
//    
//    UInt8 blue  = data[pixelInfo];
//    UInt8 green = data[(pixelInfo + 1)];
//    UInt8 red   = data[pixelInfo + 2];
//    UInt8 alpha   = data[pixelInfo + 3];
//    CFRelease(pixelData);
//    
//    UIColor* color = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:alpha/255];
//    
//    return color;

}
```

Comment: A few questions: this code tells me 'size' and 'scale' properties are not on my ViewController? How should I define these? And in pick color with point, should CGImageRef be my view (self.previewView)?